# How to keep similar row height and column width throughout all the pages in an Excel worksheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm not very good at MS Excel but I need to work with that. I have several pages in an Excel worksheet. And now I want to set the height of the 1st 2 rows of my page as 0.6cm, next 2 rows as 0.46cm next 10 rows as 0.42 and the rest of the rows in that page as 0.46cm. It is working well for the pages those I'm setting it manually.

Now I'm searching to set it up in a way so that this setting work for the rest of the pages and the pages I'm going to add later.

What can I do in this case to solve it with minimum effort? (NB: I don't have any previous experience to work with programming in Excel).

Answer (score 0):

There are two equally good ways:

1. Start with a single worksheet and format it until the internal dimensions are perfect *(rows, column, etc.)*  Then make as many copies of this perfect template as you need.
2. Start with a single sheet.  Turn on the Macro Recorder. Then format it until the internal dimensions are perfect *(rows, column, etc.).*  Then run the macro on any other sheets.

Comment: Thanks Gray's Student, I'm not much familiar with VB or Macro, is there any other ways?